# Is it possible to reply all moderators together with @all

Tags: support, moderators

I seen in Stack Overflow that whenever we need to reply in the comments section, we need to use the shortcut `@name`.

Is it possible to reply all moderators together like `@allphpmoderators` or `@moderators`?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

To contact a moderator, you can always flag a question or answer, and enter your message in the text field.

Comment: make it possible ?

Comment: i know that but it will be beter for next generation

Comment: @Learner why? I don't see a point in this. Why should I be able to alert moderators in comments to questions they probably know nothing about? It would just put even more strain on them.

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account:) kkk but atleast on the Bounty period, if person ofer more than 500+ and also i think Q does not provide strain bcause it is not compulsory to ans them

Comment: @Learner but why? What's wrong with flagging if you need to talk to a moderator? Do you have a specific question in mind that you need support for?

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account:) i told you bcause it is more complicated to reply when we are in the group of moderators with coments

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account:) and also if it is posible to login by mobile no...  only

Comment: @Learner what exactly do you mean by "moderators" - you *are* referring to the very few people on the bottom of [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/about), correct?

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account:) wel no proble, kk i want to ask any mobile.stackoverflow @softif available

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account:)bcause whenever i m free i always operate this site, but it wil takes alots of time in mobile operation

Comment: @Learner I'm not sure I understand what you mean - the need for contacting *moderators* should not arise that often.

Comment: @Learner, check your keyboard: some keys apparently don't work. :)